# How do I list the contents of the download directory in Cypress? I need to make sure that there are files of unknown name parts in there

Tags: cypress

How do I list the contents of the download directory in Cypress? I need to make sure that there are files of unknown name parts in there. Once I know the file name, it's not a problem:

```
cy.readFile('cypress/downloads/Bestellschein-xy.pdf', 'binary', { timeout: 15000 }).should('exist').should(buffer => expect(buffer.length).to.be.gt(61060));
```

But unfortunately xy changes every time.

Comment: `cy.readFile(...).should('exist')` does not test for the existence of a file. `.should('exist')` is only for DOM elements.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it myself: This way it is ensured that there is one more file in the directory after the download and the name is output for info.

File **ConfirmationPage.ts**:

```
class ConfirmationPage {
  elements = {
    bestellscheinDruckenButton: () => cy.get('.confirmationRX__dl-button'),
  }
  druckeBestellschein() {
    cy.task('downloads', 'cypress/downloads').then(before => {
      this.elements.bestellscheinDruckenButton().click()
      cy.wait(2000)
      cy.task('downloads', 'cypress/downloads').then(after => {
        cy.wait(2000)
        expect(after.length).to.be.eq(before.length + 1)
        const newFile = after.filter((file: any) => !before.includes(file))[0]
        cy.log('The new Bestellschein is: ' + newFile)
      })
    })
  }
}
export default ConfirmationPage
```

File **cypress.config.ts**:

```
import { defineConfig } from "cypress";
import fs from "fs";

export default defineConfig({
    chromeWebSecurity: false,
    reporter: "cypress-mochawesome-reporter",
    e2e: {
        setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
            on("task", {
                async downloads(downloadsPath) {
                    return fs.readdirSync(downloadsPath);
                },
            });
            // implement node event listeners here
            // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-var-requires
            require("cypress-mochawesome-reporter/plugin")(on);
            return config;
        },
        // baseUrl: 'https://qas.xy.de',
        baseUrl: "https://www.xy.de",
        experimentalStudio: true,
        viewportWidth: 1920,
        viewportHeight: 1080,
        video: false,
        watchForFileChanges: false,
    },
});
```